# Complicated model without a huge dataset

Tags: model-selection, multicollinearity, aic, generalized-additive-model, multiple-imputation

I've got a set of data that I'm trying to model.  Lots of the data is missing, so I'm using multiple imputation.  I've got about 360 observations and 13 variables.  I'm also using GAMs, but that should be really relevant (I specify the knots in advance).  In addition, I've got 4 interactions -- 2 two-way interactions and 1 3-way.  All of them are pre-specified by theory, and I see which ones I can cut from the model (using AIC) to achieve more parsimony, after fitting.

Here is my problem:  I have way too many interactions and variables for the size of my dataset, yet none of them want to come out of the model -- removing them increases AIC.  When I compare the model with interactions to the model without,  an F-tests suggest that the complicated model is quite significantly different from the simple one.  Yet because of high co-linearity, terms jump around quite a bit when I set the seed differently or come across a new data point to add.  My prediction results still have the same general gist, but inference on model terms isn't stable.

I'm not sure what to do here.  Rules of thumb suggest simple specifications for small datasets.  But simple specifications are clearly inferior.  Beyond "pick a better problem with better data," what would you suggest to someone in this situation?  My gut instinct is just to de-emphasaze inferential results and stick with prediction when I write this up.  But that feels like a coverup.  Suggestions welcome.  Apologies for the vague question.

Comment: I don't know too much about it, but the way you describe the problem makes me think that you need [shrinkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinkage_estimator). Or to put it another way, you want a different [bias-variance tradeoff](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html) than the one you're getting from your current modelling approach. [Multilevel models](http://bit.ly/YilFES) provide a principled way to trade off larger bias for smaller variance, hopefully in a way that reduces overall mean squared error. Maybe [this paper](http://bit.ly/14WeapO) will help you.

Comment: Hmmm, thats an interesting suggestion.  I'm not sure how far I'm willing to stray from unbiasedness, but this is certainly worth thinking about.  And easy enough to implement with `select=TRUE` if I do decide its the way to go.

Comment: But how would you do model selection together with shrinkage?  Would you first try to lose terms via AIC, and then apply shrinkage to the selected model?  Or shrink from jump?

Comment: Shrinkage just means moving parameter estimates toward zero; so from a certain point of view, model selection, i.e., setting some parameters of the full model to zero, is already a shrinkage approach. From this perspective, one ought to just use the full model, let whatever shrinkage approach one has chosen do its work, and then report when shrunken estimates cannot be distinguished from zero (using a bootstrap CI, perhaps).